# Return Random Namber from function in Javasctipt

Tags: javascript

i need to create something like this :

```
function randomNumber() {
 randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*14);
}
```

and then get value from this function every time i need , example :

```
function randomarray() {
myArraye[randomNumber()].image
}
```

please delete this topic

Comment: And what is your probelm/question?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: you can try below code for random number generate:  refer jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/LutoykLm/ and refer other solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363616/generate-random-number-between-2-variables-jquery

Comment: Are you trying to ask "How do I select an array element at random?" (by getting a random number between 0 and the array length - 1)

Comment: What I ask if it possible !? create function to get random number when I call him

Comment: Example : alert (random_number_function());

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getRandomEntry(list) {
  return list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
}

var images = ["img1", "img2", "img3"];
for (var ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
  console.log(getRandomEntry(images));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this type of function :

```
function getRandomNum(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: I think functional way is better.

Comment: This is a useful function in a general sense, though nothing people can't get [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) directly, but it doesn't answer the question - because the "question" doesn't actually ask anything...